# jqGrid - Icons Not Showing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I currently have a jqGrid that is loading data correctly and functioning correctly, but the icons (paging arrows, minimize arrow, delete and add icons) are not showing. If I hover over where they should be, the area is highlighted and they respond to a click. I've looked up other threads on this issue, but the version of jqGrid I have doesn't mention the directories I've seen people refer to.

The jqGrid version I'm using is Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/css/jquery-ui.theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"/>
<script src="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.7.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "loadform.php",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ["Name", "Social Security Number", "Date of Birth", "Income"],
            colModel: [
                       {name: "name"},
                       {name: "ssn", width: 200},
                       {name: "dob"},
                       {name: "income"},
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5,10,15],
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            height: "auto",
            loadonce: true,
            caption: "Assignment 5 - jqGrid",
            pager: "#listpager"
        });      

        $("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#listpager",{edit:false,add:true,search:false,refresh:false});
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <center><h1>Data Form With jQuery</h1>
    <table id="list"></table>    
    <div id="listpager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `position: 'right'`, as following,

```
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#listpager",{edit:false,add:true,search:false,refresh:false,position: 'right'});
```

Comment: I just tried it. I can tell that it moved the position of the navGrid, but the icons still won't appear.